# MySQL: Selecting from a different db type & server

Tags: mysql, database, database-trigger, federation

We are building a MySQL database (Database A) to act as a repository that needs to pull/refresh data from a different database/server. This database (Database B) is not MySQL but rather an ODBC compliant data structure for Sage 100 Accounting.

Database A: MySQl on Server 1
Database B: Sage 100 on Server 2
-- Both servers are on same LAN

I've seen a lot about FEDERATION but it seems it is only mentioned with the same database engines. Since the only substantial equivalent between these two databases is that they are both ODBC compatible, I'm trying to determine if this is still possible using Federation - or any other method.

The goal is to be able to use a MySQL trigger (despite potential performance considerations) to pull data from the Sage 100 database as needed to update the MySQL db to keep records in sync.

Is this possible with federation? If not, what other options do I have?